# Does anyone know of any application of mathematical induction in Complex Analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis, discrete-mathematics, induction

I know some applications of mathematical induction, such as D'moivre's theorem and triangular inequality, but I wanted something more, like derivatives, limits or some complex identities to which I could apply mathematical induction.

If anyone knows any material, please indicate :)

Comment: One of the most useful theorems about that if a complex function is differentiable at a point, then it is infinitely differentiable at a point is proven using mathematical induction

Answer (score 5):

How about this one?

Consider a Taylor series

$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!} x^n $$

Then for all natural numbers $k$, the $k$'th derivative of $f$ is
$$ f^{(k)}(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_{n+k}}{n!} x^n $$
with the same radius of convergence.